# How to arrange month name in array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, multidimensional-array

I have built this array from sql query and array push:

```
 $months = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'Jun', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

 $monthPicked=array();//months added to result

$rows = array_map(function($item) use(&$monthPicked){
array_push($monthPicked, $item->month);
return (object) ['c' => [
    (object) ['v' => $item->month, 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->jobcount), 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->interncount), 'f' => null]
]];
}, array_values($data));

$remainingMonths=array_diff($months, $monthPicked);

foreach($remainingMonths as $month)
{
$rows[]=(object) ['c' => [
(object) ['v' => $month, 'f' => null],
(object) ['v' => 0, 'f' => null],
(object) ['v' => 0, 'f' => null]
]];
}
```

Now, I need to arrange the months in sequence from January to December because the month name by array_push function is inserted at the end of earlier array.

Can the month be arranged in sequence?

This is the output of the array:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => July [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 6 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 2 [f] => ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => August [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 3 [f] => ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => January [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => February [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => March [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => April [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => May [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => Jun [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => September [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => October [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => November [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [c] => Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( [v] => December [f] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [v] => 0 [f] => ) ) ) )
```

I tried use this function but it doesn't work with multi array of object class.

```
usort($rows, "compare_months");

function compare_months($a, $b) {
$monthA = date_parse($a['month']);
$monthB = date_parse($b['month']);

return $monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"];
}
```

It says Error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

How I want to replace ['month'] to suit the $rows array format?

Comment: Please specify the programming language. I believe this is Php.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is PHP

Comment: Any help really appreaciated

Comment: Should be accessing using property syntax: `date_parse($a->month)` and then `$monthA["month"] - $monthB["month"]` should be `$monthA <=> $monthB`.  This is basically a typo question.  Your code already demonstrates that you know how to access object properties.